# How to setup tp-link wi-fi adsl router to use internet signal from cable modem (there is no WAN port)

Tags: router, wifi, modem

I have TP-LINK TD-8901G router and it has 4 LAN ports, but there is no separated WAN port. Also, I have one CISCO 2100 cable modem. So, how I can setup tp-link to use signal from cisco modem and to share Internet link through other LAN ports and wi-fi?

Here is the TP LINK [user guide](http://www.mondoplast.ro/download/tp-link/td-w8901g/TD-W8901G%20User%20Guide.pdf) for this model, but i don't know what to look for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your WAN port is the ADSL port and there's no way you can turn one of the LAN ports into a WAN port. So the simple answer is: no, it's not possible.